# Regular Expression sort in reverse order

Tags: javascript, regex, excel

I need a regular expression or similar. I have a series of strings in the pattern of:

```
S 8010-Y30R
7020-R
S 7020-R
3852-R10B
```

I need to order these:

```
By the last letter in the order: Y R B G
Then by the last two digits
Then by the second last letter (if any) in the order: Y R B G
Then by the two digits
Then by the first two digits
```

So the example: `S 8010-Y30R would be ordered by: R 30 Y 10 80`
The second example: `7020-R is a short version of: S 7020-R _ _ _`

I can either order these in excel... or use JavaScript and sort two arrays (one containing the color codes above and one containing the RGB version of the same).

Comment: If you have 7020-R you want it to be like R 2070? This one too a big vague.. e.g. S 8010-Y30R should be R30Y1080S? Please clarify with a better example..is it alwas two digit/two letter comparison? do you want to keep the hyphen?

Comment: It's the NTC color system. It should be red: S8010-Y30R \n 
 
First two digits: amount of black - 80 \n 
 
Second two digits: amount of color 1 - yellow 10 \n 
 
Third digit pair: amount of last color - red 30 \n 

In some of the pairs there is an S writte in fornt in some not...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Search string  
    ^[A-Z]? ?(\d\d)(\d\d)-([A-Z]?)(\d\d)?([A-Z])?$
 Replace string 
    $5$4$3$2$1
```

This assumes that always-occurring items are the four digits before the hyphen, and the hypen itself. Everything else is optional, and you don't want to keep the first letter. Each string occurs on it's own on a line.

Comment: I don't think Excel support PCRE syntax.